# How to run python script within the python interpreter in Bash

Tags: python, bash, python-3.5

I am using python3.5 to learn how to scrape data from website. And I realize IDLE is slow when the input explodes (like when I using .text to check the contents of the web). So I use Bash to test my scraper.py script.

After I enter python in Bash:

```
154-76:~ FDSM_lhn$ python3.5
```

It's hard for me to open a .py file. The only way I know how to do that is:

```python
import scraper.py
```

which is not convenient because the object I create isn't in that environment. During the test I need to check something in it from time to time.

Can anyone can help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a file called `scraper.py`, you should be able to execute it via `python -i scraper.py`. This will leave it interactive.